# App Icon is not changing in phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am working on phonegap project and Earlier i had an old icon for app.

For this, I have placing new icon in `app/www/res/android directory`.

After build the app, old icon coming only in `app/platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi`

Is there any directory to place the icon?

Where i have to place the new icon in phonegap projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your icons are located in the folders below for the respective Devices + resolutions:

`res/icon/android/*`
`res/icon/ios/*`